# Converting column of text to binary, where a set of values = 1, all other values = 0

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a column of all text that I would like to convert to 1s and 0s. First, I want to convert a list of specific values in that column to 1 and convert all other values to 0.

So in the example below, I would like to convert the words "mix" and "remix" to 1, while all other values to 0.

I'm trying to do this in pandas and I do know how to convert values, but I'm having trouble converting all other values to zero.

DF:

```
ID      Value
abc123  mix 
abc123  remix
abc123  original
abc123  original
xyz987  mix 
xyz987  mix 
xyz987  original
xyz987  original
xyz987  unofficial
xyz987  unofficial
```

Output:

```
ID      Value
abc123  1
abc123  1
abc123  0
abc123  0
xyz987  1
xyz987  1
xyz987  0
xyz987  0
xyz987  0
xyz987  0
```

Then I want to sum the Value column for each unique so that the output looks like:

```
abc123 2
xyz987 2
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`isin` chain with `groupby` `sum`

```
df.Value.isin(['mix','remix']).groupby(df.ID).sum()
Out[429]: 
ID
abc123    2.0
xyz987    2.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Win-Ben oh this is great! Any chance you would know how to convert the values in the "Value" column to 1s and 2s?

Comment: @KirklandShawty df.Value.isin(['mix','remix']).map({True:1,False:2})